# Using nullptr when it is set to a const variable

Tags: c++

I have a function in which the parameters include (const char *target = nullptr). I have to use it in my function somewhere but any attempt to do so causes a seg fault. Inside the function, I can use "nullptr" in this fashion:

```
if(currentObj->next[i] == nullptr)
```

but it does not work when I try to replace nullptr with "target". Is there any way I can replace the nullptr with the parameter, "const char *target = nullptr"?

Comment: You mean `if(currentObj->next[i] == nullptr)`?

Comment: That is what I meant, yes!

Comment: `if(currentObj->next[i] = nullptr)` is meant if(currentObj->next[i] == nullptr)? if yes try still fail?

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] of the non-working code, and tell us *how* it's not working (do you get build errors? Then what errors do you get?). Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I simply wanted to know how to use the "const char *target = nullptr" and the rest of my code does not pertain to this in any way. It does not make sense to me that you can use nullptr in the above context, but not the variable set to nullptr.

Comment: May be `currentObj` is nullptr or next is nullptr. Verify `if (currentObj == nullptr || currentObj->next == nullptr)`.

Comment: You basically say "Doing like this doesn't work", but you don't tell us *how* "it doesn't work". You need to do that or else we can only *guess*. There's just to many unknowns and too little context to say something useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is an issue with the code you didn't show to us but it is perfectly legal to make `nullptr` a default parameter.

Please, have a look at the following example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

void compare(const char *target = nullptr) {
    if (nullptr != target && 0 == std::strcmp(target, "abc")) {
        std::cout << "It is abc" << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "It is not abc" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    const char abc[4] = "abc";

    compare();
    compare(abc);
    compare("abc");

    return 0;
}
```

Check it out [live](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:20,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:20,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:'%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstring%3E%0A%0Avoid+compare(const+char+*target+%3D+nullptr)+%7B%0A++++if+(nullptr+!!%3D+target+%26%26+0+%3D%3D+std::strcmp(target,+%22abc%22))+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22It+is+abc%22+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++%7D+else+%7B%0A++++++++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22It+is+not+abc%22+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++const+char+abc%5B4%5D+%3D+%22abc%22%3B%0A%0A++++compare()%3B%0A++++compare(abc)%3B%0A++++compare(%22abc%22)%3B%0A%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:54.308093994778076,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g92,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'0',intel:'0',libraryCode:'1',trim:'1'),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14',selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+9.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:45.97651026222455,l:'4',m:51.042810098792536,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+9.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:48.957189901207464,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:45.691906005221924,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Here, if nothing is being passed to the `compare` function, `target` parameter has a `nullptr` value. Otherwise, it has the value you have passed to the function.

Furthermore, you may want to know the difference between constant pointer and pointer to constant. Constant pointer is a pointer that cannot be changed - it always point to the same object given:

```cpp
char * const example = nullptr; // reading from right to left: constant pointer to char
example = "abc"; // throws an error
```

Pointer to constant is a pointer whose pointed value cannot be changed:

```cpp
const int * ptr = &some_int; // reading from right to left: pointer to constant integer
ptr = &some_other_int; // legal, no error
*ptr = 2; // illegal because the pointed value is constant
```

So, in your case, default parameter `target` can be changed since in the body of the function and no error will appear:

```cpp
void compare(const char *target = nullptr) {
    target = "aaa"; // no error
    ...
}
```

Comment: You might want to point out that `target == "abc"` doesn't compare the strings, but only the pointers themselves.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yep, will add that. Tnx

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Wasn't me. Thanks for this, you helped a lot!

Comment: I accepted the answer, but I'm new so I cannot cast a vote.

Comment: What's `if (target == "abc")` ... You compare a pointer with another pointer! `"abc"` is of type `const char *`.

Comment: That's what i wrote as a note and I am aware of that. That was just a part of the explanation to the OP

Comment: I dubt about your code although it appears to run correctly. I've substituted the fix constant "abc" in the main with a variable `abc`. First time I've declared `const char * abc="abc"` with this declaration the code runs, the next try I've declared `const char abc[4]="abc"` in this last way the code doesn't run. What's the meaning? ;)

Comment: I will check once I am back at my laptop

Comment: I've disassembled the code and I discovered that the GNU g++ (7.4.0) compiler uses "abc" as the same pointer to "abc" (`LC0`) both in main and compare function ... that is the way your SW runs. ;)

Comment: @SirJoBlack you are right. I was writing this answer on my way out of the house and could think a bit more about it. It is updated now. Thanks for pointing this out to me